# not able to run this command in php

Tags: php, command

I am trying to download a file from a remote website. I need to run this command in command line through php. But it is not happening. Please help me.

```
echo $name;
        $param="ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/emdb/structures/EMD-{$name}/map/emd_{$name}.map.gz";
        echo $param;
        $command="wget ".escapeshellcmd($param)." -O /home/nagarjun/mercurial-1.4.1/clussym/trunk/dataset/emd{$name}.map.gz -e use_proxy=yes -e ftp_proxy=authproxy.serc.iisc.ernet.in:3128";
        echo "<br />$command";
    //$outputofexecutable = shell_exec($command);
    passthru($command);
```

Comment: Enable `error_reporting`, look into the error log, capture `stderr` (per `2>&1` perhaps) to see what is and what isn't happening.. Then use PHPs built-in curl functions instead.

Comment: yes, all i did was changing the destination path to "/var/www/html "

Answer (score 0):

I can see two explanations:

- wget is not found because the environment variables are not the same: use an absolute path
- Your Apache (or any other webserver) user does not have permission to execute this command: you can use sudo, please see https://serverfault.com/questions/157272/allow-apache-to-run-a-command-as-a-different-user